# HTML5 audio: setting currentTime in IE 10

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I built a player for HTML5 animations and everything has been working fine on IE9, Chrome, FF, iOS, Android, and Surface.  With the recent release of IE10, I'm now working through a bug where setting currentTime of the audio track is not working.  I made a quick fiddle with the following code:

**HTML**:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://images.apple.com/html5/showcase/audio/letsgosurfing-thedrums.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
<button>Jump to middle</button>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$('button').on('click', function(event){
  $('audio')[0].currentTime(15);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RMEmB/1/

This works as expected on all browsers that support mp3 files **except** IE10.  It doesn't matter if you start playing the sound first or not.  Has anyone worked around this problem?

Specifically IE 10 on Windows 7, I don't have Win 8 nearby to test.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure you are using a valid HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` on your live page?

Comment: Yes.  I also added a note to the original post that this is on Windows 7.  What OS did you use?

Comment: Same, Windows 7 here.

Comment: Just FYI, it works well on IE10 @ Win8.

Comment: Well alright.  Let me check my environment and see if that is the cause.  Thanks.

Comment: So it turned out to be the VM that I was using.  This works as expected on a physical windows machine running IE10.  Thanks all for giving it a try and getting me to push deeper.